# Correct way to insert (and detach) cascade on @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to support both cascade and non-cascade on @ManyToMany relationship.

Given this code:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Category> categories;
}

categoryRepository.save(new Category(null, "name 1"));
categoryRepository.save(new Category(null, "name 2"));
productRepository.save(new Product(null, List.of(new Category(null, "3333"))));
```

I got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.product.entity.Category; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.product.entity.Category
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy99.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.product.ProductApplication.lambda$t$0(ProductApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

After modify the model to:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH })
  private List<Category> categories;
}
```

The code run successful.

But, if I change `productRepository.save(new Product(null, List.of(new Category(null, "3333"))));` to `productRepository.save(new Product(null, categoryRepository.findAll()))`, then I will get another error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.product.entity.Category
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy90.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

I want to support both cascade and non-cascade on @ManyToMany relationship. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, the code to save entities must be in a `@Transactional` method